# Contact Form Not Submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, zurb-foundation

Using Zurb Foundation 5 and contact form will not submit. Nothing happens when clicking submit button. It should replace form with a thank you message and send the form data to my email. Any help greatly appreciated...

HTML:

```
<body>    
  <section id="footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns">
            some other stuff
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns">
            <form id="myForm" data-abide="ajax">
                <div class="contactform">
                    <div class="name-field">
                        <label>Your name <small>required</small>
                        <input id="name" type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
                        <small class="error">Be sure and leave your name.</small>
                        </label>

                    </div>
                    <div class="email-field">
                        <label>Email <small>required</small>
                        <input id="email" type="email" required>
                        <small class="error">Oops, you forgot your email.</small>
                        </label>

                    </div>
                    <div class="text-field">
                        <label>Message <small>required</small>
                        </label>
                        <textarea id="message" required></textarea>
                        <small class="error">I see you're the quiet type. How about a short message?</small>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('opened', '[data-reveal]', function () {
var modal = $(this);
$(window).trigger('resize');
});
</script>

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>

<script>    
    $('#myForm')
    .on('valid.fndtn.abide', function () {
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();

        //Data for response
        var dataString = 'name=' + name +
            '&email=' + email +
            '&message=' + message;

        //Begin Ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"php/mail.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                $('.contactform').html("<div id='thanks'></div>");
                    $('#thanks').html("<h2>Thanks!</h2>")
                    .append("<p>Glad to hear from you "+ name +"! I'll be in touch soon.</p>")
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn(1500);
            },
            }); //ajax call
            return false;
    });
</script>
```

PHP

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$msg = "

Name: $name
Email: $email
Comments:
$message
";

$to = "parker.w.gibson@gmail.com";
$subject = "Web Form";
$message = $msg;
$headers = "Web Form";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

edited to separate JS

Comment: I believe, you listed HTML, but for it to run it also needs some JavaScript, am I right?

Comment: Do yu have any console errors..??

Comment: shouldn't u be writing the form submission inside the `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: @Outlooker, I'm getting a "POST http://www.uiowa.edu/~lifeclas/gps/php/mail.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)" console error.

Comment: @OlegDubas, posted JS

Comment: Although it isn't the solution, try using an object instead of string:  `var dataString = {'name': name, 'email': email, 'message': message};`. It will help you avoid data escaping problems

Answer (score 0):

I think this is some sort of a cross domain issue.Your code is actually attempting to make a Cross-domain (**CORS**) request, not an ordinary POST. Modern browsers will only allow Ajax calls to services in the same domain as the request. To enable CORS on your remote server go to the following web page which gives instructions for the different types of servers .Try reading [this](http://enable-cors.org/) .

**FYI**

[CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)